# parsing google calendar data using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

this is been bugging me for a while. I am trying to get event titles from my google calendar feed using getJSON and eventually parsing it using JSONparse callback. Unfortunately I cant make it work. I am coming across bunch of solutions everywhere but really not what I am looking for. I could make it work if I use the google js api but I trying to use pure jquery.

Here is what I have

```
var eventName = '';
var gclaData = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/********%40gmail.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&max-results=3&futureevents=true&alt=json';

$.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
        for(var i=0; i<=data.length; i++){
            eventName += JSON.parse(data[i].entry.title.$t)+"<br>";
        }
        $('#outputTitle').append(eventName);
    });

});
</script>
<div id="outputTitle"></div>
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/HEZaK/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont understand what you are doing, first the for is wrong because the data object it doesnt have any length, the feed field is an array, so you should do:

```
data.feed.entry[i].title.$t
```

and second the $t value is a string so you cant pass it to JSON.Parse, or you can but its worthless.

Maybe the final code you are looking for:

```
var eventName = '';
var gclaData = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/somugus%40gmail.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&max-results=3&futureevents=true&alt=json';

$.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
  for(var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++){
     eventName += data.feed.entry[i].title.$t+"</br>";
  }
  $('#outputTitle').append(eventName);
});
```

Comment: @daver--yes thats exactly what I was looking for. I kinda had an idea that probably my loop was wrong but didnt understand what might be wrong in that. But thanks for pointing that out.